# Apache not serving static files to any other machine than localhost

Tags: wordpress, apache, configuration, localhost, mamp

My problem is really simple. My MAMP server does not serve static files (css and javascript) to any other machine than localhost (I have tried with my iPhone and another mac on my local network). They can get the html, but they do not get the static files.

I get the same error for all:

```
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

I have a fresh install of wordpress and MAMP. It doesn't work on any wordpress theme. I have turned off my firewall.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was, the wordpress site url was set to localhost, so localhost was in all the pathnames. Stupid of me to not see it earlier...

I just changed the url in Setting --> General in wordpress admin panel.